# Using `nextval` and `currval` inside one CREATE TABLE

Tags: postgresql, sequence, recursive

Let's say that we would like to model a team of people that can have subteams like so:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE seq_teams;
CREATE TABLE teams (
    tid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT nextval('seq_teams'),
    sid INTEGER REFERENCES teams(tid) DEFAULT currval('seq_teams'),

    name VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL
);
```

So, if the team is not a "subteam" of any other team, then `tid` and `sid` have the same value. Otherwise, `sid` is the id of the superteam for team `tid`.

So, if I want to insert a superteam, I can do just:

```
INSERT INTO teams (name) VALUES ('superteam 1')
```

Is there a guarantee that `tid` and `sid` will be the same in this case? Is there some better (well known) design that can deal with recursive data structures?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you have posted works OK, and is guaranteed to insert the same IDs.

The other way of designing this is to have a separate table that stores the hierarchical relationships, but you don't really need to do so unless you have many:1 or many:many relationships.